MassTransit, create scoped IPublishEndpoint with IServiceScopeFactory does not publish message
My aim is to publish an audit message on RabbitMQ so that another service can consume it. I am capturing the audit inside the DbContext class by overriding the SaveChangesAsync method. My first thought was to provide the IPublishEndpoint via Dependency Injection into the DbContext class but this did not work. When I "dotnet run" the project it freezes on startup without any errors and after a few hours I discovered it had to do with the UseBusOutBox().
 x.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<SetupDbContext>(o =>
    {
        o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        o.UseSqlServer();
        o.UseBusOutbox();
    }); 

I then decided to provide the IPublishEndpoint interface with IServiceScopeFactory and it seems at first a success as the service start up and it publishes a message without errors but then I realised that the message was never published. It even did not write to the outbox tables in sql.
So, I tried testing this situation in a more straight forward scenario. I added the code I was using to publish an audit message to an action method in a controller. I tested it and still it did not publish the message. If I inject IPublishEndpoint into the controller with Dependency Injection the publish works perfectly.
Somewhere I am missing configuration or it is not possible to provide the IPublishEndpoint via IServiceScopeFactory. I would be very glad if someone can help.
Here is my code:
Controller method
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SupplierDto model)
        {
            
            await using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();

            var pe = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPublishEndpoint>();
            await pe.Publish(new AuditContract
            {
                Action = "test",
                ChangedColumns = "test",
                Changes = "test",
                EntityName = "test",
                NewValues = "test",
                OldValues = "test",
                PrimaryKey = "test",
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
            });
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();
        }

Program.cs (All the masstransit config)
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<SetupDbContext>(o =>
    {
        o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        o.UseSqlServer();
        o.UseBusOutbox();
    });
    //Consumers
    x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<TenantCreatedConsumer>();
    //Prefix for queues
    x.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter("setup", false));

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("setup-tenant-created", e =>
        {
            e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, 5));
            e.ConfigureConsumer<TenantCreatedConsumer>(context);
        });
      

        cfg.Host(builder.Configuration["RabbitMq:Host"], "/", host =>
        {
            host.Username(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Username", "guest"));
            host.Password(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Password", "guest"));
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

UPDATE - 2024/12/18
So the problem is the UseBusOutBox. If I take out the line o.UseBusOutBox(); the message is actually published and my consumer receives the message. Thus, the Bus outbox does not intercept the message anymore but publish it directly to the message broker:
 x.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<SetupDbContext>(o =>
    {
        o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        o.UseSqlServer();
        //o.UseBusOutbox();
    });

The problem is, we need to use the Outbox function. I am not sure if this is a bug or done on purpose. The fact is, you can't use IServiceScopeFactory to retrieve a scoped service of IPublishEndPoint if you are using the outbox function. Unless there is something else we can do to get this working?

You should resolve all dependencies from the container, and call SaveChangesAsync after the Publish call.
The sample does this as well via an indirect dependency.
A scope is already created for your controller action method, creating another one is duplicative.

I forgot to include the SaveChangesAsync(). I did include it now in the question. With it, it still does not publish the message. Also, it seems you have missed on why I am trying to use IServiceScopeFactory. I normally resolve dependencies from the container using DI but in this case I need it inside the DbContext class and if you DI IPublishEndpoint inside there the service won't start.

Chris, I forgot to ask in my first comment, where exactly in the sample is the example of an indirect dependency?
